# Authentication Error In Update_with_media function Twitter

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have this code:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(my_key,my_secret,{ :site => "http://api.twitter.com",        :scheme => :header})
token_hash = { :oauth_token =>"my_access_token",:oauth_token_secret =>"my_access_secret"}
user_access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
user_access_token.post("http://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.format?status=test&media[]=http://s3.amazonaws.com/fbappshq-assets/datas/7826/large.png")
```

It gives this error:

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Could not authenticate you\",\"code\":32}]}"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [the API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) it states:
`POST statuses/update, this method expects raw multipart data. Your POST request's Content-Type should be set to multipart/form-data with the media[] parameter.`

You may have to use a technique similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/ichiban/1075327) in order to `POST` multipart data to the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this discussion thread

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11280

You can check this soluctions, might work for you.